# Why do test_pathlib and test_shelve fail in make test for building Python 3.7.4, and should I care?

Tags: python-3.x, build

Building Python 3.7.4, installing in a non-standard location since I don't have sudo.  I'm getting two errors when I did a make test:

```
$ python3 test_pathlib.py
.........................................s................F.........................................................s.........................s...................F.........................................................................................................................sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
======================================================================
FAIL: test_touch_common (__main__.PathTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_pathlib.py", line 1690, in test_touch_common
    self.assertGreaterEqual(st.st_mtime_ns, old_mtime_ns)
AssertionError: 1564431558252148297 not greater than or equal to 1564431558252721000

======================================================================
FAIL: test_touch_common (__main__.PosixPathTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_pathlib.py", line 1690, in test_touch_common
    self.assertGreaterEqual(st.st_mtime_ns, old_mtime_ns)
AssertionError: 1564431558622160959 not greater than or equal to 1564431558623350000

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 395 tests in 0.733s

FAILED (failures=2, skipped=114)

$ python3 test_shelve.py 
test_bool (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_constructor (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_get (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_getitem (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_items (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_keys (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_len (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_pop (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_popitem (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_read (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_setdefault (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... ok
test_update (__main__.TestAsciiFileShelve) ... gdbm fatal: couldn't init cache
```

Any ideas as to why this is failing?